# getting the index path of section when pressing on a button in this section

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview which contains sections instead of rows, each section contains a button, a have made a inaction function for this button when pressed, I need to get the indexPath of this section when this button is pressed, I used those function:

```
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
 NSString *orderId = [self.tableValues objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

both returned nil the problem is in the indexPath value, 
but any idea why?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are clicking button instead of your cell.

To make it working, add tag to button and when click, get the tag when click button. So your code will change to

```
NSString *orderId = [self.tableValues objectAtIndex:tag_that_you_get_in_IBAction];
```